# Retrieve file stored as varbinary(max) filestream in SQL 2008 with MS Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2003

I have a MS Access 2003 mdb acting as a front end for a SQL 2008 back end. The back end contains a table with a varbinary(MAX) filestream column. I can use the front end to upload files to the database using a stored procedure. I'd like to store images in the BE for display in the front end, but I can't figure out how to bind the files stored in the db to an image object in the mdb. I thought of exporting the file in the db to a temp location, then binding the path to the image, but I can't seem to get at the file without the SQLFileSteam API which Access doesn't have a reference to. Does anyone know of a solution to this or a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read out the varbinary(max) field into a Byte variable, then save that Byte to a (temp) file and bind your image control to that (temp) file

Comment: I had to connect to the server with ADO using the sql driver as the Jet engine does funny things with the binary column, but after that it worked fine. Thanks